# Removing map and set from headers

Tags: c++

I am hosting a DomJudge server for a coding assignment (C++) in my college. The assignments are usually sport programming problems, but we don't want students to use STL features such as map or set. We want them to implement them on their own. So for that, i removed `stl_map.h` and `stl_set.h` from the headers.

Is this safe to do? Are there any better alternatives that we can opt for?

Comment: "we don't want students to use stl features such as map, set". It's really a bad idea.

Comment: It in an introductory course, we want them to know how they are implemented and for them to be able to implement them properly.

Comment: We want students to be capable once they graduate and should not depend too much on the company they work for to teach them.

Comment: Do you follow up these assignments with letting them use `std::map` and such? So they learn the virtue of not reinventing the wheel? Otherwise, I concur with those above me. You just teach them a crippled version of C++, not something useful.

Comment: Yeah, once they have implemented Red-black tree or AVL tree, whichever one they are comfortable, with, we will start enabling these features of c++. The course isnt about teaching them c++, it is about teaching them basic data structures. If we allow them to use direct implementations, they would not learn how they work, or when they are useful. I think one should not just know how to use a tool, but also how the tool works.

Comment: Fantastic. I wish more courses had a syllabus like that :)

Comment: While this may be a good idea (knowing the internals, being aware of complexity of certain operations, understanding trade-offs), it is crucial for programmer to know existing tools and their proper usage. Then, they can solve the actual problems rather than spending weeks on re-inventing the wheel. That being said, I hope it is a follow-up course that teaches how to use standard C++ library.

Comment: @DarkCoderRises Why bother removing the headers? If you tell students that they must not use a certain feature of the library, and they use it anyway, giving them a failing grade for the assignment would be rather appropriate.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek, as I said in the previous comment, it's just for this one assignment, where they have to implement these things directly. For later assignments, we will encourage them to use the std features directly.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Since it an automated judge, and it is a huge class, we would have to figure out a way to judge if they are using it or not. As there are always people who will try to game the system.

Comment: c has no map or set and c/c++ is not a language :P

Comment: @user463035818 I am sorry for the error in my writing, I will update it

Comment: I appreciate your patience of defending your lecture style here, but please please dont teach your students about "c/c++", please make them aware that c and c++ are two different languages

Comment: @user463035818 Thank you for that specific feedback. We used to just teach c language. This is the first time we are trying to get c++ into the curriculum. In fact, today only I am going to take the first class on c++, and this was my only agenda, to tell them that c++ is very different from c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not bother with removing the headers. Instead, you can examine the headers you want to "disable" and see what include guards it uses. For example, `stl_map.h` could look like this:

```
#ifndef __STL_MAP_H__
#define __STL_MAP_H__

// content ...

#endif /*__STL_MAP_H__ */
```

Then, you can use `#error` directive:

```
#ifdef __STL_MAP_H__
#  error "stl_map.h is forbidden in this assignment!"
#endif
```

The [`#error directive`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/error) renders the program ill-formed and causes the current translation unit fail to compile.

---

One thing you must consider is to **where** insert `#error`. Prepending it to the source won't work, since includes won't be catched. Appending may work, but note, that one can easily do `#undef __STL_MAP_H__`. Placing it after last include is probably a good idea. It all depends on how do you want to/are allowed to process the source code.

As @PeterT correctly noticed you can also add to command line `-D__STL_MAP_H__`, so the content of the header won't be processed (as the include guard will be already defined), but again - one could easily do `#undef __STL_MAP_H__` before the `#include`.

Comment: so basically append that to all translation units? Since prepending won't catch all cases. For less helpful error messages you could also add `__STL_MAP_H__`, etc. defines to the compile-flags.